# Local notification every ten minutes

Tags: codenameone

I wrote:

```
LocalNotification localNotification = new LocalNotification();
        localNotification.setId("Gratitudine");
        localNotification.setAlertTitle("Pratica della Gratitudine");
        localNotification.setAlertBody("Leggi e ripeti interiormente");
        localNotification.setAlertSound("/notification_sound_bell.mp3");
        // alert sound file name must begin with notification_sound

        Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 1000, // first notification
                LocalNotification.REPEAT_MINUTE // Whether to repeat and what frequency
        );
```

It works.

What is a correct way to repeat the notification every ten minutes? The only available options are: `REPEAT_NONE`, `REPEAT_MINUTE`, `REPEAT_HOUR`, `REPEAT_DAY`, `REPEAT_WEEK`.

Same question for any arbitrary number of minutes (for example 4 or 13).

Thank you

Comment: Arbitrary repeat durations aren't supported. I'm not sure why but I guess there's inconsistent native support for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/index.html) it doesn't seem to be possible. You can only get it to repeat every minute. To do what you want you may need to setup additional notifications at the intervals. This means that if you want to cancel them you will need to do that when the user clicks on the notification and opens the app, or on some other event.